# How to identify isochoric process from the problem's wording?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

Problem 19 from NEET's *Solved Paper 2013*:

> The amount of heat energy required to raise the temperature of $\pu{1 g}$ of helium at NTP from $T_1$ to $T_2$ (in kelvin) is
>
> \begin{align}
> &\text{(a)}~\displaystyle\frac 3 8 N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}(T_2 - T_1)
> &\quad
> &\text{(b)}~\displaystyle\frac 3 2 N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}(T_2 - T_1) \\
> &\text{(c)}~\displaystyle\frac 3 4 N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}(T_2 - T_1)
> &\quad
> &\text{(d)}~\displaystyle\frac 3 4 N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}\frac{T_2}{T_1}
> \end{align}

My chemistry teacher said the “*language of question*” gives away the process is isochoric and suggested to use the following equation to solve the problem:

$$\mathrm dQ = nC_V\Delta T = \frac f 2nR\Delta T$$

yielding the correct answer $\text{(a)}~\displaystyle\frac 3 8 N_\mathrm{A}k_\mathrm{B}(T_2 - T_1).$

How can this be deduced conceptually? What *exactly* points to an isochoric process in this case?

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Search for molar heat capacity of ideal gases at constant p ( isobaric process ) and constant V ( isochoric process ) // Look also at molar versus specific heat capacity. // Generally, search properly before asking. The site tries to avoid answering questions for which answers can be easily found.

Comment: 1 g of He and 3/8 point there.

Comment: I guess the implication of the problem statement, especially NT**P**, suggests (slightly) that the process is at constant pressure.  But it certainly is not clear.

Comment: @ChetMiller c_v(1 g He) =(approx) 3/8Na.kb, cp(1 g He)=5/8Na.kb // I do agree the wording itself (NTP) speaks for isobaric process, but reportedly correct formula speaks for isochoric process.

Comment: Note that NTP cannot be assumed to be at constant p, as it does not assume constant T either. My interpretation is NTP is meant as  initial conditions.

Comment: @Ujjawal Mishra where did you get struck?

Comment: @Infinite **Where it is written that the Volume is constant.** I think there should be constant pressure, because in question NTP is mentioned. So, why we are using that Heat given = n Cv ΔT ?

Comment: At NTP both temperature and pressure is constant. Then what do you mean by raising temperature.

Comment: For your better understanding first forgot "at ntp" in the question. Then understand the definition of internal energy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The heat given to a system can be utilised in increasing its internal energy or doing work against the surroundings. This is popularly known as first law of thermodynamics. 
 The change in the internal energy brings the change in the temperature and vise versa. So to increase the temperature one should increase the internal energy of the system. We know that, $$ \Delta U = nC_v \Delta T $$ According to first law of thermodynamics, the heat given to the system at constant volume is known as internal energy. ( $\because$ work done ($W$) = 0 at constant volume )$$ \Delta Q = \Delta U $$ $$\implies \Delta Q = nC_v\Delta T $$ I think this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: This avoids the major question why isochoric and not isobaric. :-)

Comment: In question, they had mentioned 1 gram of Helium. So, now the moles of helium is fixed, and the temperature is changing. Thus, now there are two possibilities, that the volume can change or the pressure will change. Now, how we will decide that what will change ? @Poutnik

Comment: @UjjawalMishra  Reread all what has been posted, including comments. It is there. Molar heat capacity of monoatomic ideal gas is (3/2)R for isochoric process, (5/2)R for isobaric one.

Comment: It should be pointed out that ∆U=ncv∆T is true for isochoric processes with real substances (assuming constant heat capacity), any process with an ideal gas, but not generally true for any process with any substance.

Comment: No you are misconcepted. It is true for all processes.

Comment: You can verify in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Poutnik Sir please answer this question with reliable explanation. Because I want to understand this important concept. Pardon me for inconvenience. ( I'm new in Thermodynamics lesson.

Comment: @UjjawalMishra Chemistry SE site does not support answering without explicit significant effort to understand it on your own.